# Passing data between activities with parcelable

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

So my app is like this. I have a list view, `Categories`. When a user clicks a category, a new activity, `Products` is launched. Some products that he can buy appear. After he selects what he wants, he can click the *Order* button, to go to the `Checkout` activity.
Right now, in order to send data from `Products` to `Order`, I have a `parcelable` class, and use it like this :

```
Intent orderActivity = new Intent(Main.this, Order.class);
orderActivity.putExtra("parcel", listOrdered);
```

Thing is, that maybe a user wants to buy things from multiple categories. So after he selects from products from category 1, he goes back to the `Categories` activity (the products that he selected need to be kept), selects another category, and chooses products from there too.

My question is: Can I use the approach from above, to do this? Or do I need `onAnctivityResult()` and things like that?

Comment: Just a little bit OT. Why don't you use a DB to keep track of selected products? It would be also persistent across application closing.

Comment: Never thought of that...I was thinking of using DB only to remember previous orders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should organize your code as follow :

In activity `Categories`, maintain a list of selected products, it should be parcelable or serializable, which is easier.

Call `startActivityForResult` when you call Products and pass it both the selected category and the list of selected products. When user is done selecting new products, call `setResult` so that the `Categories` activity can get the new list of selected products via an override of `onActivityResult`.

There are other options, more advanced and more object oriented but they are not as standard as this method and are a bit more advanced. But if you are curious, you could have a look at injection frameworks like [RoboGuice](https://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) or [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger) to get a shared `ProductManager` instance inside all activities you display.

Comment: Hi RCI, I agree, but the questioner seems to be beginning, so as a first step it would be more important to master the basis of the android framework before tackling a more advanced technology.

Comment: Yeah, true. But also, without using any DI framework, a normal singleton could do the trick.

Comment: If and only if the state of the singleton is persisted to handle application life cycle.

Comment: Thanks...I used the first option...since I am an android novice...Maybe in version 2.0, the app will use the second solution :)